# Writing in files without overflow

Tags: java, file-io, io

I have the following code:

```
FileWriter filewriter = null;
try { filewriter = new FileWriter("outUser.txt", true); } 
catch (IOException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }

try {
    filewriter.write(s1+"\n");
    filewriter.flush();
}
catch (IOException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }
```

Its supposed to write on `outUser` file the `s1 string` and a newline. It only writes `s1`, the newline is not written.  I also tried with a new string that equals `\n` and append it to `s1` when written but still didn't work. Do any of you have some answers for me?

Comment: How do you verify that no newline is written? Whatever you use might expect `\r\n` as the line ending (as most Windows tools do).

Comment: could you share the output upon running your program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line feed should be there, but keep in mind that different OS-es have different new line characters.
If you're out of luck you can always try [`BufferedWriter.newLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

Different OS have different ways to represent newlines.

For Example,`\n` is used in UNIX but `\r\n` is used in Windows.

[This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n) answers why windows uses `\r`

You can use [System.lineSeparator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29) which returns the system-dependent line separator string.

Answer (score 0):

Open your `outUser.txt` with an text editor like notepad++ and enable the 'non-printable'-chars. You should see an `CR/LF`, which is the `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
FileWriter filewriter = null;
try {
                     filewriter = new FileWriter("outUser.txt", true);
                     BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);  
                  } catch (IOException e1) {
                     e1.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  try {
                      buffwriter.write(s1+"\n");
                      buffWriter.newLine();
                     buffwriter.flush();
                     }
                  catch (IOException e1) {
                     e1.printStackTrace();
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
FileWriter filewriter = null;

         try {
             filewriter = new FileWriter("c:\\outUser.txt", true);
          } catch (IOException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
          }
          try {
              filewriter.write("hi"+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
              filewriter.write("asd");
             filewriter.flush();
             }
          catch (IOException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
          }
```

Use Line Separator Property to print nextline to File .